# Call a Method from another Method Android

Tags: java, android, methods, spinner

I am not sure this workaround is the correct way to achieve my goal of having a prompt text in a spinner. What happens with this application is the spinner navigates to another Activity via an Intent and when the user navigates back to the Main Activity with the spinner they have two ways back. One with a Button and a click event the other by clicking the device BACK button. I am trying to call the code in the click event from the method that manages the device BACK button
I do not know how to call the click event from the device BACK button Method

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Use BACK BUTTON\n\n"+"On the Screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // I want to call goBack(View view) from here
    // +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
}

public void goBack(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent( PageTwo.this, MainActivity.class );
    startActivity( i );
}
```

The reason I use this Intent to navigate BACK to the Main Activity is it reloads the variables in the Spinner

Comment: This will cause you a problem. A new instance of Main Activity will open and calling activity will also remain in stack as you are not closing it.

Comment: @Ramil How do I close the stack I assume this will cause memory leaks can I just put the reload of the spinner in a method and only reload it and do the navigation back with onBackPressed

Comment: You can finish the calling activity and reload spinner in onResume. problem solved :)

Comment: @Ramit I hate to be dense but do I keep the Intent I say no OR how do I write the Intent to include the onResume() OR where do I palace this call on PageTwo or on the Main Activity sorry I am lost

Comment: let me explain. 1. Do not override onBackPress in page2 (so it will automatically destroy on back press) 2. override onResume method in main activity and update spinner here. (when you will come back in main activity from page2 onResume of main activity will call and will update your spinner)

Comment: no need of intent code

Comment: @Ramit So I loose the Back button call onBack and only navigate back with the device BACK button ON Main to I put the onResume inside the onCreate or make it a separate method

Comment: ok got it, so you can call goBack as it is and just write finish in goBack in place of intent code. This will work? Sorry for causing confusion.

Comment: @Ramit OK got it I think I used finish in the onBackPress and goBack then on the Main Activity I wrote this public void onResume() and super.onResume with a call to a method reLoad that reloads the spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `goBack(View)` is most likely from an `onClick` setup in your layout XML. Since you aren't using the view, just pass `null`:

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
  goBack(null);
}
```

Comment: Rummier That did the trick not sure why I did not think about that Still learning as a 7th grader this is like learning French when you live in Germany

Comment: Rummier So if I create a Method on the Main Activity that reloads the spinner can I call that on the PageTwo Activity with an Intent OR where would I do the calling of the reLoad() method

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get you right, if you just want to go back to the activity which started another activity, you can just call **finish()** method of Activity class:

```
     @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

[finish() reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())

Comment: I understand that if I call finish() but when I use that concept the spinner does not get reloaded and the user can not make another trip back to the last experience by selecting it from the spinner My GOAL was to reload the spinner hence the use of the Intent to navigate back to the spinner